# Why does calling `.map` on a `pandas DatetimeIndex` call the function with the entire index?

Tags: python, pandas

My script kept crashing and after a long search I identified the culprit to be the behaviour of the `.map` method of a `pandas DatetimeIndex`, namely, it (unexpectedly) *first* calls the specified function on the entire index, before (expectedly) calling it on its elements individually.

Here is an example (without any practical application) that shows the problem.

```py
import pandas as pd
index = pd.date_range('2020', freq='MS', periods=3)
_ = index.map(print)
```

This results in the index being passed to the `print` function:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-02-01 00:00:00
2020-03-01 00:00:00
```

**Is there a reason for this?** Or is this a bug?

The same problem/behaviour does *not* occur when using an integer Index:

```py
import pandas as pd
index = pd.Index([1, 12, 192])
_ = index.map(print)
```

Here the index itself is not passed to the `print` function:

```
1
12
192
```

I'm using python 3.8.8 and pandas 1.2.4.

**EDIT**

A previous version of this question mentioned Jupyter and IDLE, as I initially had an example that resulted in different results in these two environments. In this example that is not the case, and I do not think the environment is actually a factor - the code above gives the same result in each.

Comment: Not reproducible, I get 3 (using pandas 1.3.3).

Comment: Crashes on Spyder also. (using Python 3.9.7 and pandas 1.3.4)

Comment: Can you post the full error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: The curious thing is, that I do not get an error message when I run the code (as I normally would when running into an Error). As you can see from the green tick next to the box [1]. It's only when I try to see the contents of the `index` variable that I get the error message about session requests that is printed below (the `index` variable is not special; I get the same result on `1+1`). If there is a trick I don't know, let me know what else I can do to get the stack trace.

Comment: I've heavily edited the question to show the issue in a more direct way, and which does not crash.

Comment: Interesting. `.apply` and other similar functions used to include warnings about how they might internally try to call the passed in function on the input data in various ways, so that the function shouldn't have side-effects.

Comment: At this point I believe you might want to open an issue in the pandas repo

Comment: Seems like someone [beat me to it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44392) :)